# barman new version not installed by yum

Tags: linux, postgresql, yum, repository

as all know barman (http://www.pgbarman.org/blog/) now have new version 2.2

I download  barman RPM on my linux redhat machine

I also installed the epel repo

but when I download the rpm from some un-clear reason it download the previous version - barman-2.1-1 and not the high version ? - WHY!!!

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i barman
barman-2.1-1.rhel7.noarch



  example:

  yumdownloader  barman
  Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id
  epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                            

 |  23 kB  00:00:00
 epel-debuginfo/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                  

 |  22 kB  00:00:00
 epel-source/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                     

 |  22 kB  00:00:00
 barman-2.1-1.rhel7.noarch.rpm

 # pwd
 /etc/yum.repos.d

 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   1056 Jul 13 20:16 epel-testing.repo
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   1050 Jul 13 21:28 epel-testing.repo.rpmnew
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root    949 Jul 24 15:27 epel.repo
```

Comment: I'm not following. You say the new version is 2.2, but for some un-clear reason it downloaded the previous version... 2.2. (barman-**2.2**-1.rhel7.noarch.rpm)

Comment: update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you install rpm file? For me update is working fine. See result below:

```
[root@centos-linux ~]# rpm -qa | grep barm
barman-2.1-1.el7.noarch
[root@centos-linux ~]# rpm -F https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgbarman/files/2.2/barman-2.2-1.el7.noarch.rpm/download
[root@centos-linux ~]# rpm -qa | grep barm
barman-2.2-1.el7.noarch
```